# Consume kafka messages from a topic which is going to be updated after every certain time

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I want to consume a topic which will be updated after certain time.
lets say currently topic name is topic_may and next month there will be a topic named topic_june. would I be able to do this?

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), could you please explain your use case and reason behind it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Smile sure,
I have a kafka producer whch creates topic on weekly basis by adding date on topic's suffix eg topic_9_5_22. so i want to write a consumer which will be able to consume the current topic as well as next topic which will have different suffix.
u got better clarity?

Answer (score 0):

Use a topic pattern (regex) e.g. `topic_.*`, or you can make the regex tighter if you want to limit it to month names.

By default, Kafka will check for new matching topics every 5 minutes.

Comment: i tried it but after using this I am getting some other error-
JoinGroup failed: The coordinator is not aware of this member. Need to re-join the group.